# increase spark cluster size automatically

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cloud, hadoop-yarn, autoscaling

I have a spark cluster with yarn and hadoop in Azure using Hdinsight. 
My cluster consist of 2 heads and 3 worker. 
My question is : "is it possible to increase the cluster size automatically ? "
thank you

Comment: Its not a question about spark. More about Azure features.

Comment: suppose the cluster is not deployed on azure, is it possible to increase its size automatically ? (autoscalling)

Comment: I cannot guarantee about Azure but it is possible on AWS.

Comment: It can be done on Google Cloud as well

Comment: it can be done on Azure ? How ?